I am trying to run the below code on Pycharm and i get the below error on Magic Exception
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredFileLoader
from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain_text_splitters import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_chroma import Chroma

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()

loader = DirectoryLoader(path="data",
                         glob="./*.pdf",
                         loader_cls=UnstructuredFileLoader)
documents = loader.load()


text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2000,
                                      chunk_overlap=500)
text_chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
documents=text_chunks,
embedding=embeddings,
persist_directory="vector_db_dir"
)

print("Documents Vectorized")

ERROR
C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py:1601: FutureWarning: `clean_up_tokenization_spaces` was not set. It will be set to `True` by default. This behavior will be depracted in transformers v4.45, and will be then set to `False` by default. For more details check this issue: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/31884
  warnings.warn(
Error loading file data\UPL Leave Policy.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\vectorize_documents.py", line 13, in <module>
    documents = loader.load()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\document_loaders\directory.py", line 117, in load
    return list(self.lazy_load())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\document_loaders\directory.py", line 195, in lazy_load
    yield from self._lazy_load_file(i, p, pbar)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\document_loaders\directory.py", line 233, in _lazy_load_file
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\document_loaders\directory.py", line 223, in _lazy_load_file
    for subdoc in loader.lazy_load():
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\document_loaders\unstructured.py", line 107, in lazy_load
    elements = self._get_elements()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\document_loaders\unstructured.py", line 228, in _get_elements
    return partition(filename=self.file_path, **self.unstructured_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\unstructured\partition\auto.py", line 186, in partition
    file_type = detect_filetype(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\unstructured\file_utils\filetype.py", line 102, in detect_filetype
    return _FileTypeDetector.file_type(ctx)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\unstructured\file_utils\filetype.py", line 135, in file_type
    return cls(ctx)._file_type
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\unstructured\file_utils\filetype.py", line 145, in _file_type
    if file_type := self._file_type_from_guessed_mime_type:
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\unstructured\file_utils\filetype.py", line 185, in _file_type_from_guessed_mime_type
    mime_type = self._ctx.mime_type
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\unstructured\utils.py", line 155, in __get__
    value = self._fget(obj)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\unstructured\file_utils\filetype.py", line 369, in mime_type
    magic.from_file(file_path, mime=True)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\magic\__init__.py", line 178, in from_file
    m = _get_magic_type(mime)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\magic\__init__.py", line 165, in _get_magic_type
    i = _instances[mime] = Magic(mime=mime)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\magic\__init__.py", line 73, in __init__
    magic_load(self.cookie, magic_file)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\magic\__init__.py", line 332, in magic_load
    return _magic_load(cookie, coerce_filename(filename))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\chtbt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\magic\__init__.py", line 225, in errorcheck_negative_one
    raise MagicException(err)
magic.MagicException: None

I had copied .dll files into the sys 32 folder.
Pycharm's GUI libraries has also been installed..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
